# Can I pass in a dynamic price into my typeform?

Tags: wordpress, web, typeform

I'm trying to pass in a price into my typeform, and trying to implement a short of a payment flow with Stripe integration. The samples I have seen for this all involve static, hard-coded pricing coming from the Typeform itself; I would like to pass in the price as a hiddenfield parameter and have that be the item that is charged.

However, I am having a lot of trouble seeing examples of how to implement this. Does anyone have any guidance? 
I know how to pass in parameters into the form - but how to implement the dynamic pricing based on those parameters seems to be... not possible?

Would love any input. TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typeform supports natively Stripe payments in their form. It lets you accept payments via credit card easily.

Unfortunately, if you want your price to be dynamic, you can't pass directly it as a parameter of the typeform (called [Hidden field](https://help.typeform.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029114712-How-to-use-Hidden-Fields)).

If your price depends on a calculation, like the number of items, you can use the calculator feature ([help center article](https://help.typeform.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029250492-Calculator)).

And ask those questions to determine the price to pay.

Here is a [simple form](https://picsoung.typeform.com/to/wK8smw) to order pizzas at different prices depending on the type.

Here is how it was made on Typeform:

first: Setup a different price per pizza type
[image: Setup a different price per pizza type]

second: Update the total price depending on the number entered
[image: Update the total price depending on the number entered]

Hope it makes sense :)